# Use passcode to validate user if touch id validation fails

Tags: ios, objective-c, validation, keychain, touch-id

I'm using touch id to validate use to log into my app.

My code

```
- (void)evaluatePolicyWithCompletion:(LASuccessBlock)successblock failure:(LAFailureBlock)failure
{
    LAContext *context = [[LAContext alloc] init];

    // show the authentication UI with our reason string
    [context evaluatePolicy:LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics localizedReason:NSLocalizedString(@"UNLOCK ACCESS TO LOCKED", nil) reply:
     ^(BOOL success, NSError *authenticationError) {
         if(success)
             successblock();
         else
             failure(authenticationError);
     }];
}
```

It return the result of the touch id validation.

Here what if user chooses to enter password instead of touch id,do i have to redirect user to my login in screen to enter his/her login in credentials or is there any way to use device passcode to validate user.

Comment: Have a launch page with two options - validate with touch - validate with password and let the user decide. There is no way that I know of getting user device lock password.

Comment: @SamB My current implementation is the same way as u have suggested,but my client's requirement is to use passcode if user fails to validate using touch id.